# Issues updating Magento 2 Extension Namespace to uppercase

Tags: magento2, extensions, configuration, setup-di-compile

I think there were previous issues with Magento 2 allowing extensions namespaces to be lower case when we initially submitted ours. But now, it seems that Magento 2.2.x enforces uppercase first character, as we got this error:

*Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'vendorname\extensionname\Block\BlockName' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.*

However, when we updated our extension code to use uppercase everywhere (except the name in the composer.json file), our extension can't seem to find the various classes we now have within Model and Block, and got the following error after compiling:

*PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Vendorname\Extensionname\Block\BlockName' not found in /var/www/magento89/generated/code/Vendorname/Extensionname/Block/BlockName/Interceptor.php on line 7" while reading response header from upstream*

The code for the Block in question looks like this (fairly straight forward):

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Extensionname\Block;

class BlockName extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductsCollection()
    {
        $block=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products.list');
        return $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
    }
}
```

**Edit: adding in the Interceptor code**

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Extensionname\Block\BlockName;

/**
 * Interceptor class for @see \Vendorname\Extensionname\Block\BlockName
 */
class Interceptor extends \Vendorname\Extensionname\Block\BlockName implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface
{
    use \Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = array())
    {
        $this->___init();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes = array())
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getImage');
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes);
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('getImage', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there somewhere in the database that might contain the old namespace somewhere, and it's using that instead of the new updated uppercased namespace?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Delete the contents of your `var/generated/code` folder and then run `setup:di:compile`

Comment: @andyjv I've tried this already, but comes out with the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please rename `vendorname/extensioname` to `Vendorname/Extensionname`

Comment: I've tried completely renaming the Block name to a few different things, but none seemed to work, unfortunately.

Comment: Strange for me is that : Fatal error: Class 'Vendorname\Extensionname\Block\BlockName' not found in /var/www/magento89/generated/code/Vendorname/Extensionname/Block/Blockname(/Interceptor.php on line 7

Why in first place with have BlockName and after that I see Blockname? There has to be some problem with filename? Any chance to get access to code?

Comment: Ah, I think the lowercase n might've been a typo by me. Have edited above.

Comment: What is in app/etc/config.php? Is there correct module name?

Comment: Yes, the module is named correctly in app/etc/config.php

Comment: Do you use somewhere <block class="\Vendorname\Extensionname\Block\BlockName"? It should be :
block class="Vendorname\Extensionname\Block\BlockName"

Comment: Nope, the class name is correct everywhere in the extension, no leading slashes in the XML.

Comment: Is this module installed through composer or it is in app/code? what is the full path for BlockName.php file?

Comment: It's in app/code and the full path is /var/www/magento89/app/code/vendorname/extensionname/Block/BlockName.php

Comment: OK. Can you rename vendorname/extensionname to Vendorname/Extensionname (uppercase)?

Comment: Ah, that did it! But shouldn't these be lower case when they get zipped up and submitted to Magento Marketplace? Everything under vendor comes out as lowercase so I assume the directories under app/code should be lowercase too?

Comment: Nope. It should be uppercase. Modules from vendor directory are using composer.json. If you will check for example magento\module-cms you will see in composer.json this line :

"psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Cms\\": ""
        }

Also pls accept my answer if it works now :)

Comment: Ah, so composer handles that and changes it to lowercase once it's been downloaded that way? Interesting.